# Concatenate a String and a variable in a .conf file

Tags: python, configuration, config

I wanted to ask how I can concatenate a string and a variable in a .conf file.
Example:

In the **settings.conf** file:

```
# The credential is in another, separate passphrase.conf file, declared as 'password'
    credential = passphrase/${password} 
      url = "XYZ.${credential}XYZ.com"
```

If i do it as shown in my example, I get an error that I have the wrong password, so somehow it is not concatenating correctly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('passphrase.conf')
pass=config['__REPLACE WITH CONFIG SECTION__']['password']
url = "XYZ"+pass+"XYZ.com"
```

Comment: this doesnt work in a .conf file :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple way how to concat string and variable.

```
password_var = 123456
new_string = f"This is my password: {password_var}"
```

Output: 
This is my password: 1234

Comment: it is in a .conf file as well. not a .py :) so this isnt working...